# make e act like e! in vim

Tags: vim, alias

I'm giving vim a spin for the first time. I've gone ahead and done

```
set hidden
```

in my .vimrc because I don't mind leaving files lying around unsaved. But now it seems kinda pointless to type `e!` and `bnext!` and so on instead of just `e` and `bnext` and so on. Can I make those commands imply the override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
cabbrev e <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'e!' : 'e')<CR>
```

Then, when you type `:e` it should do this `:e!`

More info can be gotten [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I think you mean `cabbrev e <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'e!' : 'e')<CR>` though. I'm going to leave this open in case someone shows me in how to do it globally across all the file switching commands.

Comment: no, its the way I did, look at the doc. And you can do it by yourself across all the file commands, just edit it up. `cabbrev bnext <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'bnext!' : 'bnext')<CR>`

Comment: I am looking at the doc and also I understand the logic of what the line does. Also I've tried it. Note how your second example takes the  form I used; we're replacing e with e!, not the other way around.

Yes, I can individually replace all the commands, and I'll do that if I have to--just hoping for something more. If I don't get it, I'll accept this answer 'cause it works :)

Answer (score 0):

just do `:cab e e!`, works for `:cab q q!` and non saved files are closed.

Comment: This is not a good idea. No try a search for the letter e like so `/e`. Notice that it expands to `/e!`. The Elite Noob answer does not have this problem.